# write a function that takes string arguments with quotes

Tags: r

I want to be able to call the function below with something like this

```
conditional_prob_bool(Class=='democrat',V1=='y',df)
```

and have

```
consequent_bool=df$Class=='democrat'
```

and

```
antecedent_bool=df$V1=='y'
```

inside the function body.

But it does not seem to work the way I want, possibly because of the quote marks. Can someone suggest how I can change the code so that I can get these assignments?

```
install.packages("mlbench")
install.packages("mice")
library(mlbench)
library(mice)
data("HouseVotes84")
imputeddf=mice(HouseVotes84,m=1,maxit=50,meth='pmm',seed=500)
completedData <- complete(imputeddf,1)
df=completedData
df$names<-rownames(df)
conditional_prob_bool=function(spec1,spec2,df){ 

  consequent_bool=df$spec1 
  consequent_event=df[consequent_bool,] 

  antecedent_bool=df$spec2 
  antecedent_event=df[antecedent_bool,] 

  return(prob(intersect_event(consequent_event,antecedent_event,df),df)/prob(antecedent_event,df)) 
} 

#Currently when I run it I get
> conditional_prob_bool(Class=='democrat',V1=='y',df)
[1] NaN
#however manually running the body like this, I get what I want.
> consequent_bool=df$Class=='democrat'
> consequent_event=df[consequent_bool,]
> antecedent_bool=df$V1=='y'
> antecedent_event=df[antecedent_bool,]
> prob(intersect_event(consequent_event,antecedent_event,df),df)/prob(antecedent_event,df)
[1] 0.8376963
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think you can't write directly `Class=='democrat'` as an argument in your function. One way might be to create two more args to separate `Class` and `'democrate'`for example. But before that, you should  have tried your function line by line to see if it works (by returning a value for example) because it seems you have wrote in one block without testing it.

Comment: It seems to me like you are trying to implement non-standard evaluation. Try replacing `consequent_bool=df$spec1` by `eval(substitute(spec1), df)` and similarly for `spec2`.  Have a look at the `substitute`example in http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html. It might help.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.  
And sorry, I am not sure what you mean by write it directly? I think that is what I did. Thanks again

Comment: @matt By directly I mean when your give to your arg `spec1` the followed value `Class=='democrat'`. I think your should split it just for this case in two args : let's say `spec11` and `spec12` and `spec11` will get the value `Class` and `spec12` the value `'democrat'` so your line in your body would look like : `consequent_bool = df$spec11 == spec12`

Comment: Hi Mbr, Thanks. I just tried your suggestion but I am getting the same NaN. I used a function signature like: conditional_prob_bool=function(var1,spec1,var2,spec2,df) and consequent_bool=df$var1==spec1 and antecedent_bool=df$var2==spec2 and I tried calling it like this: conditional_prob_bool(Class,'democrat',V1,'y',df) and also like this: conditional_prob_bool("Class",'democrat',"V1",'y',df)

Comment: Thank you ikop. I tried this: consequent_bool=df$eval(substitute(spec1), df) and antecedent_bool=df$eval(substitute(spec2), df). But I am getting the error: attempt to apply non-function

Comment: @matt Like I said, do it one by one line. Check if the first line works, then go for the second etc. if you're not sure. It might seem like dumb but it's better to debug thant stay with a no working function. Comment all your lines except the first then call your function this way : `(Class,df)` and try to return this line : `consequent_bool=df$spec1`  by writing `return(consequent_bool)` and check if it returns the result expected.

Comment: hmm, interesting idea Mbr.

Comment: @matt Does your function `prob` exist ? Or is it in a specific package ?

Comment: @Mbr Mbr  This is prob. prob<-function( e,  s) {
  return(nrow(e)/nrow(s))}

Comment: @matt and `intersect_event` is also a function you created ?

Comment: @MbrMbr intersect_event=function(a,b,df=df){
  return(df[intersect(a$names,b$names),])}

Comment: @matt Alright it works now. Don't forget to give the function(s) you have created if your function use it if you want people to try your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the function :

```
conditional_prob_bool <- function(spec11, spec12, spec21, spec22, df){ 

  consequent_bool <- df[,spec11] == spec12
  consequent_event <- df[consequent_bool,] 

  antecedent_bool <- df[,spec21] == spec22
  antecedent_event=df[antecedent_bool,]

  return(prob(intersect_event(consequent_event,antecedent_event,df),df)/prob(antecedent_event,df))
}
```

Results :

```
> conditional_prob_bool('Class', 'democrat', 'V1', 'y', df)
[1] 0.8376963
```

As I told you, if your function doesn't work, debug it row by row to see where the error comes from.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying the debug method you suggested. On stackoverflow is there a way to acknowledge that the solution provided is correct? I tried it and it does work.

Comment: @matt on the left of my answer and under the vote down button